# HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i am trying to run my asp.net application in vs.net 2010 but i am getting an error?:

"HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler."

how can i fix this?

Comment: to be clear are you running it in IIS 7 from visual studio?

Comment: Several solutions have been found here : [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87107/how-do-i-fix-404-17-error-on-win-server-2k8-and-iis7 "stackoverflow")

Answer (score 3):

got it working:

run aspnet_regiis -i in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319