# Deploying MVC application in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7

I have made a MVC 3 application and I am running a windows server 2008 r2.  I am trying to deploy it and when I get the files loaded up it and navigate to the url it just shows me a file directory of my project.  Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: You have the application pool set to run ASP 4.0? With Pipelinemode set to Integrated?

Comment: Try aspnet_regiis -i and Recycle IIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574356/how-to-publish-asp-website-using-iis7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some case it could be from IIS 7 not recognizing the extension less urls. I'm not 100% sure if that's the issue here but surely something to check.

See if you guys have this update on your system:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

The technical details are available at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Comment: Appreciate it, I was saving it to somewhere else other than the default folder and that was causing it to not recognize it.

Comment: I was importing the project and instead of putting it in the C:\Inetpub\wwwroot it was putting it into another location. It worked after I did that.