# aspnet_regiis does not exist

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, web-deployment, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87107/how-do-i-fix-404-17-error-on-win-server-2k8-and-iis7) issue, but while trying to fix it as per the suggested answers, I cannot find aspnet_regiis in my computer, I checked the matching .NET library as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx#FindingTheCorrectVersion), but the file is not there.

Comment: what version of asp.net, and what server os?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This fellow](http://forums.iis.net/p/1175490/1971354.aspx) had a problem with a missing `aspnet_regiis` file.

He solved it by **repairing his .Net framework installation.**

That might be worth a try?

Comment: Argh! So much plumbing to keep track of. At least it's an easy fix.

Comment: fyi path to file is C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe (though version may be different for you)

Answer (score 10):

I am sure either you have not installed .NET Framework or haven't included it in your **Environment Variables**. Please install and then just add its path in Environment variables.

The default location for `aspnet_regiis` is :

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3` or `v4` whatever your framework is.

Comment: and add the path to your environment variables!

Answer (score 2):

run Visual Studio **as Administrator** and try again :)

Comment: Do you mean "**as** Administrator"?

Comment: I sure do mean "as.."

Comment: I ran cmd as Admin in order to decrypt with aspnet_regiis

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4