# Windows 2008 / IIS 7 Website works fine in 64bit mode does not work in 32bit mode

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am building web site on windows 2008 / iis7 that requires 32bit mode for reporting functionality. Everything working fine with app pool allow 32bit applications set to false, but when I set app pool to allow 32bit application set to true I get 404 error because the path being called is getting changed.
Below is clip from the IIS log:

> uat set to false - Works fine 304 means that the request is cached
>   2012-07-09 18:29:56 xxx.xx.xxx.xx GET /Metron/images/flags/ae.png - 80
>   - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.2;+MS-RTC+LM+8)
>   304 0 0 109
>
> uatext set to true -  /Metron is removed from the path and browser
>   throws a 404 error. A 404 error means the request item has moved or
>   cannot be found.  2012-07-09 18:24:33 xxx.xx.xxx.xx GET
>   /images/flags/ae.png - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.2;+MS-RTC+LM+8)
>   404 0 2 93.

Comment: Forgot to detail that you can see in the log file /Metron is being removed when set to enable 32bit applications is set to true, hence the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even though the .NET framework you are trying to use is available, it is probably not properly bound to the IIS installation.  Navigate to c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ then to the directory corresponding to the version of .NET you are trying to use.  The install the framework by: aspnet_regiis.exe -i.  See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx.  See also this StackOverflow question: [How do I fix 404.17 error on Win Server 2k8 and IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87107/how-do-i-fix-404-17-error-on-win-server-2k8-and-iis7)