# 404.17 error - requested content appears to be script

Tags: asp.net, http, authentication, iis, iis-7.5

I have a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87107/how-do-i-fix-404-17-error-on-win-server-2k8-and-iis7);

- IIS 7.5
- Server 2008
- ASP.Net 4.0 web site

The error I get when trying to run the site is this:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
>   The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
>
> ...
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different hander.

Now here comes the weird part:

### THE WEIRD PART

The weird part is that on the develop server -- *which is similar in every aspect to the production server* -- everything runs smoothly.

Here's a list of things I **cannot** try, because I don't want to mess with the sever (it hosts many other sites):

- Reinstalling .Net
- Reinstalling IIS
- Reinstalling *anything*
- Running aspnet_regiis

Here's what I *did* try:

- Republishing the site
- Restarting the application pool
- Changing the application pool to .Net 2.0 and back to .Net 4.0
- Switching around between Integrated and Classic pipeline mode
- Enabling 32-bit mode
- Taking a look at Handler Mappings

Eventually I created a new application pool, and it *sort of* started working.
**Q) "Sort of"?**
A) Yes, sort of.

Now the site only works when the (new) app pool is set to `.Net 4.0`, `Integrated`,
and the site's Authentication has `ASP.NET Impersonation` set to `Disabled`.

*Any* change to these settings sets the server yelping "404.17" all over again.

**Q) What's wrong with that?**
A) What's wrong with that is that I NEED ASP.NET Impersonation for the site to function properly.

As always, your guidance is most needed.

Comment: Did you see this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Usually this error occurs when you have the right IIS version installed to the respective .net framework. If it was a version (not installed) issue then you would have got a different error message. Anyways, I think by now you have resolved your matter, but I like to share some words with anyone else having this problem. These error messages gave me so much headache all last week and I had tried everything.

Best remedy is always to re install the latest .net in latest visual studio. And the important thing to do is uninstall the existing IIS(express or whichever you have) and re install it first. Then download the latest visual studio. This way visual studio installation can easily access you IIS and add the necessary application pool.

As for the error 404.17, it could simply be because the right application pool has not been assigned for the appropriate dot net version. If the right version is not there re installing visual studio is the only way I know. Also, I think you can try downloading another version of the Visual Studio too. For eg, download the ultimate if you have professional or vice versa. Hope this helps someone with similar problem.

Comment: To install ASP.net 4.5 on windows server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2736284/how-to-install-asp.net-4.5-on-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

Installing this windows server feature *http activation* is, what was missing for me.
[image: missing feature httpactivation]