# Deploying VS2010 ASP.Net website on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, publish

I know there are related posts here on this forum and another resources but I got stuck with this and couldn't proceed. Problem is I've done a website with VS2010 when I publish it to a FTP server and navigate to the url address I got an error.

Here are the things that I've done:

- I've enabled IIS services and static content
- I've revert to parent the staticFile under handler mappings
- I've registered the asp.net again in command prompt(the regiis.exe thing)
- In IIS manager i've added my website adress under sites, stopped default web site and started mine.
- I've added my site to classic.NET AppPool(integrated,and v4.0)
- I've enabled the default browsing..
- I've done all the advices that generally covered..

Here is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension" />
        <defaultDocument>
             <files>
                 <add value="AnaSayfa.aspx" />
             </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: what error are you getting? you have not included it in your question.

Comment: HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found - The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler this is the error

Comment: are you allowing ASAPI AND CGI to run? I'm not seeing that in things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

The following post has some answers to this same question.

[How do I fix 404.17 error on Win Server 2k8 and IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87107/how-do-i-fix-404-17-error-on-win-server-2k8-and-iis7)

Hope that helps.

EDIT: I see you've tried most of these...Sorry.