# Unable to start debugging on the web server. IIS7.5 VS2015 Community .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I am using IIS 7.5; Visual Studio Community 2015;  The website is MVC.  Framework 3.5

This is the first MVC website I've worked on.  After downloading the source from the repo I get this error when trying to debug.  "Unable to start debugging on the web server.  Could not start ASP.NET debugging.  More information may be available by starting the project without debugging."
Research into this error has pointed to path redirects in the config file, of which there are none in the project.
Running the project without debugging results in

> "404.17 - Not Found: The requested content appears to be script and
>   will not be served by the static file handler."

Which I believe to be a byproduct of the MVC format, but I've tried multiple variations of the url and none worked, some with 404.17 and some with 404.0.
I've tried moving the project to framework 4.0, which my tutorial on MVC used, but that caused a large number of dependency issues, so I'm abandoning that path for the time being.

What I have been able to do is make changes and publish them to a new test site on the production server.  So I know the code is good, for a certain value of good.  But I'd like to step through, see values, and have a shorter debugging turn around.

What other steps can I take to allow visual studio to debug this project properly?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762287/script-not-served-by-static-file-handler-on-iis7-5)

Comment: See also [How do I fix 404.17 error on Win Server 2k8 and IIS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87107/how-do-i-fix-404-17-error-on-win-server-2k8-and-iis7)

Comment: Also [Error: Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx)

Comment: @stuartd, Thank you for you suggestions, I have tried everything posted and it has had no visible effect.  Perhaps I should have mentioned that other, asp.net projects work fine, and that my test machine hosts a webpage without issue.